# Passing struct to class constructor

Tags: c++, struct, constructor

I need to initialize my struct values in a classes constructor , but I do not know the correct way to pass it to the constructor

I will be getting the key and value to be pushed in data and len and then pass it to my constructor

```
struct Val{
    std::vector<int> Data;  
    std::vector<int> Len; 
};
class Node {
   public:
    Val value;
    std::vector<std::string> key;               
   
   public:
    Node(std::string key, Val value){
       this->key.push_back(key);
       // code to push value for Data and Len vectors 
    }
    Node(){}
};
int main(){
  std::string key="Hi";
  int d=10;
  int l=5;
  // I need to push these three elements
 // d and l must be pushed to the vectors Data and Len in struct respectively
}
```

How do I pass the values to my Node constructor so that I can do a push_back to the vectors in struct, both the values to be pushed is being found and stored in an integer variable

Comment: Please describe what data struct you want to achieve. Key as a vector looks strange. Also the last sentence sounds like nonsense.

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can look toward the following approach:

```
struct Val{
    Val(int d, int len) { // Adding a constructor that takes two ints
        Data.push_back(d); 
        Len.push_back(len);
    }
    std::vector<int> Data;  
    std::vector<int> Len; 
};

class Node {
    Val value;
    std::vector<std::string> key; // Are you sure in this?               
public:
    Node(std::string k, Val val); // Here you define whatever logic you need
    Node() = default; // Defaulted default constructor
};

int main() {
    Node n("foo", Val(21, 42));
}
```

*I have some questions about the use of the `vector` as some `key`.*

Also, **big thing to note** here:

```
Node(std::string key, Val value){
    this->key.push_back(key); 
}
```

How would the compiler distinguish the `key` that is the parameter and the `key` that is the data member of the `Node`. Same question for the `value`.

These parameters should have some other names, otherwise they [shadow the data members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

As to the update of the question, you should look toward this implementation:

```
class Node {
    Val value;
    std::vector<std::string> key;               
public:
    Node(std::string k, Val v) : value(v) {
        key.push_back(k);
    }
    Node() = default;
};
```

Comment: If I run this i'm getting a error `undefined reference to `Node::Node(std::string, Val)'`

Comment: @Zebra that's because you need to define you constructors, these are only declarations.

Comment: can't we do a push inside the construtor? As mentioned in my edited question?

Comment: What would you push? You have a `Val`, but you have nothing to put in the `Val`. Zebra, I'm certain you're asking the wrong question, but I'm unable to figure out what the question should be.

Comment: @Zebra you may want to take a look at this [thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) after considering what I've put here for you.

Comment: @user4581301 I added main function and elements I want to push in

Comment: @Zebra check the latest edit, other than this, there's not much to add. You may need to step back and take a look at your classes design once again.